# Using wp-postratings to rate user on profile pages

Tags: buddypress, profiles, plugin-wp-postratings

I'm using wp-postratings on my site and I want to include it on the buddypress profiles of my members so other users can rate them. I place the function on the profile page but it doesn't do anything when a rating is clicked. Any ideas on what I can add to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that it will not be as easy as adding something small to make it work.

Plugins like WP-Postratings store their data on a post-by-post basis. But BP members are not posts. So you would have to intercept the way in which the plugin stores its ratings data natively, and save it to users instead.

Moreover, you'll have to modify/extend the markup and JavaScript created by WP-Postratings so that the current "item" being rated on is the member's user id, rather than the post id. Then, because the rating happens via AJAX, you'll have to make sure that the new id is sent properly in the request, and that the server-side handler is set up to expect member data rather than post data.